# Link/HREF Validation using jQuery or Javascript and RegEx

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have an input form where users can fill out a profile for their internal tool that they are submitting. There is a `link` field that allows the user to enter a link to this tool.

The following formats are accepted:

```
http://
https://
file://
\\server\path\to\file.txt
W:\
```

I am trying create a javascript function to validate the input to make sure it is in one of the above mentioned formats.

I have found some generic URL validation regEx strings but none of them seem to include the local paths of files.

Here is a quick example of a function that works just fine for the top 2 needed formats but when it comes to network paths, I can't find anything that I can get integrated into one easy function.

```
var message;

var myRegExp =/^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?$/i;

var urlToValidate = "\\server.domain.com\path\file.txt";

if (!myRegExp.test(urlToValidate)){
  message = "Not a valid URL.";
}else{
  message =  "Its a valid URL.";
}
alert(message);
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/carlhussey/ebg4m278/

I am looking for a solution to validate the standard web protocols as well as network/file shares.

Comment: `"\\server.domain.com\path\file.txt"` won't be what you think it is ... because \ is an escape character

Comment: hmm, well I have the urls stored like that in the database and when the browser renders them to the page, they appear to be valid. If the user entered the URL in the same format as above, how could I make that work? The above format is a valid URL is it not?

Comment: there's a difference between what comes from a database and what you've posted ... you posted a var declaration, not data coming in from an external source ...

Comment: I get that but the user is going to enter the path in manually, just like the type it into their address bar when connecting to another format on the network `\\server\path\file.txt` as this is a valid windows path to a file. Since we know that this path is valid and correct in syntax, It should "pass" this validation. Databases and storage aside, I am trying to make sure that a URL that is entered by a user whether it be a HTTP protocol or network based file share is in the valid format. If you have another suggestion on how this should be enforced, I am open to it..

Comment: I was simply pointing out the string in your code example, as written, would not validate - I have no further insight into your issue